# use Backbone js Node js and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, backbone.js

I've been following Developing Backbone JS Applications http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/ which has been very helpful so far.  I've followed chapter 5 to the end... now I want to use Backbone and Node with MySQL rather than with MongoDB.

I've looked carefully at the various combos of Backbone, Node and MySQL in these archives, but the thing I definitely don't want to do is use PHP between my JS and my MySQL databases: I want to use Node js.

I'm trying to understand how the whole MV* idea of Backbone ties in with a MySQL database, when using a self-written Node js server (as in this book).

### Update

How does this:

```
var Book = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    author : String,
    releaseDate : Date,
    keywords : [ Keywords ]
});
// Models
var BookModel = mongoose.model('Book', Book);
```

work in the context of an MySQL dbase?  Oh, you've added that thing about the APIs being different.  It might be nice to be told how to find out about them.

Comment: Include a mysql connector, and use it instead of mongodb. the apis and structure will be very different, but that's likely outside the scope of a single so question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to install the mysql connector and use it instead of mongoose.

```
>npm install mysql --save
```

As far as replacing all of your mongoose calls with mysql, that will be very different because they are two very different database systems. With mysql, you'll have to create a database, and then create tables that will represent your models, just like you would in php (using SQL). Giving you a conversion method by method wouldn't make sense due to the differences between mongodb and mysql.

I don't know of any, however, there may be modules out there that allow you to create models(tables) in mysql with a similar api to what mongoose has.

Documentation on the mysql module can be found here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql

Comment: With a quick search i found https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql-orm which will have a somewhat similar api to mongoose. Definitely not 1:1, but it will allow you to use it without writing sql.